# MDX Calculated Member SubCube

Tags: ssas, mdx

I am relatively new to this depth of MDX, but here is my dilemma. My goal is to implement a calculated member using a .Net Stored Procedure. The calculation (XIRR) will be based on a set of cash flow dates and cash flow amounts. Ideally this would be a calculation in my cube that is available as a measure to Excel/Browser users.

So to start simple I am just trying to implement my own COUNT calculated member/measure (not even using .Net) to say count the # of members in a given dimensions based on the current context. So lets say I have a dimensions Customer with a Customer Id Key. And let's say there are a total of 100 customers in my database. So Count(Customer.CustomerId.AllMembers) would be 100. Now when you start using the browser and say filter on Customer.CustomerId.&1, Customer.CustomerId.&2 (customer id 1 and 2) I would expect my count calculated member to return 2 but it returns the total 100 count. I have tried using exists. I am sure there is something that I am just fundamentally not understanding yet.

Hopefully this makes sense, would hugely appreciate any help from someone that has a good understanding of SSAS/MDX and calculations. Thanks in advance.

Marty

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have some issues here, I did when I tried to do a similar thing.

Your calculated member is not honouring the client sub-select, which is normal. What in theory you would do is create a dynamic set, and then use that in the calculated member to force the dimension count to be evaluated in the context of the subcube your filters have created. Mosha has a good article here: http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2007/08/25/mdx-in-katmai-dynamic-named-sets.aspx

So you'd end up with something like:

```
CREATE DYNAMIC SET CurrentCube.Customers AS
EXISTING(Customer.CustomerId.CHILDREN);

CREATE MEMBER CurrentCube.Measures.CustomerCount AS
Customers.COUNT
```

Now the real problem you'll have is a bug in SSAS https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/484865/calcuated-member-with-a-reference-to-dynamic-named-set-kills-the-cubes-performance so the code above, which will probably work just fine locally, will kill a production cube. This was an exciting learning experience for me.

See if you can get any of the workarounds to work, I couldn't.

I was able to get what I wanted, but I had to create query-scoped dynamic sets as part of the MDX query, I wasn't able to create it as a cube object:

```
WITH DYNAMIC SET Customers AS
EXISTING(Customer.CustomerId.CHILDREN);

MEMBER Measures.CustomerCount AS
Customers.COUNT

SELECT
Measures.CustomerCount 
ON COLUMNS
FROM [Cube]
WHERE Customer.CustomerId.&[1]
```

Let us know how you get on.

Comment: Thank you for pointing me in the right direction. I am going with a solution for now where I used a Dynamic Named Set along the Dimension associated with my measures needed for my XIRR (cash flows). Using this in combination with EXISTING in my calculated measure gives me an accurate SET of cash flows. I will eventually want to figure out a better solution that would handle cutting across the cash flows with other dimensions or other dimensions used  for the Filter/SubCube. But this will work for now. Thank you very much!!