# How to get count of all currently selected members of dimension

Tags: ssas, olap-cube

I have got a cube with date dimension:

```
Period
- Year
-- Quarter
--- Month
---- Date
```

I need to get count of all dates, selected by user (f.e. in Excel). I have tried to use calculated members like:

```
[Period].[Period].CurrentMember.children.count
```

It is good when 1 month is selected. In other ways (selected only few dates or Quarter) it returns the count of children of the next level of hierarchy.

```
Descendants([Period].[Period],[Period].[Period].[Date]).count
Descendants([Period].[Period].CurrentMember,[Period].[Period].[Date]).count
```

So I tried to use `Descendants`. The results are good when 1 element on any level is selected. But one you select f.e. 2 month in one Quarter - it gives counts of all elements.

How can I get count of all selected elements on Date level?

I have also tried:

```
[Period].[Period].[Date].count
[Period].[Period].[Date].CurrentMember.count
COUNT([Period].[Period].[Date])
COUNT([Period].[Period].[Date].CurrentMember)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work out multiselect in Excel, you can try *Dynamic Set* technique. Assume your `[Period]` dimension has `[YQMD]` hierarchy, then try the following
`CREATE DYNAMIC SET SelectedDates AS (
    [Period].[YQMD].[Date] ) 
 CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[SelectedDatasCount] AS (
    SelectedDates.count
 )`
Refer to this [SO article](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17747468/1010622) and [MSDN discussion](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/a6b21a43-0a8c-4936-8e9a-9ac5f6fd174d/how-to-use-dynamic-set-to-fix-multiselect-issue-in-excel?forum=sqlanalysisservices). Unfortunately, Mosha's article is no longer available.
Caveat - solution with Dynamic Set can hinder query performance.